# Script to remove specific strings in file name

Tags: shell-script, file-management

I am trying to come up with a bash script to remove parts of a file name on CentOS. My file names are:

```
119903_Relinked_new_3075_FileNote_07_02_2009_JHughes_loaMeetingAndSupport_FN_205.doc
119904_relinked_new_2206_Support_Intensity_Scale_SYCH_SIS_264549.pdf
119905_relinked_new_3075_Consent_07_06_2009_DSweet_CRFA_CF_16532.docx
29908_relinked_new_2206_Assessor_Summary_Report_SERT_I_OTH_264551.pdf
009712_relinked_new_3075_Consent_07_06_2009_CWell_DPRT_check_CF_16535.pdf
```

I would like to remove `119903_Relinked_new_` from the file names. The end result should be:

```
3075_FileNote_07_02_2009_JHughes_loaMeetingAndSupport_FN_205.doc
2206_Support_Intensity_Scale_SYCH_SIS_264549.pdf
3075_Consent_07_06_2009_DSweet_CRFA_CF_16532.docx
2206_Assessor_Summary_Report_SERT_I_OTH_264551.pdf
3075_Consent_07_06_2009_CWell_DPRT_check_CF_16535.pdf
```

I have been trying multiple scripts but coming up short. The number before `_Relinked_new_` is different in most cases and the file extensions vary across `.pdf`, `.docx`, `.doc` etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And the R of `relinked` can be either `r` or `R`, is that right?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [prename(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html) tool (it might be called `rename` or `prename` or `perl-rename` depending on your system):

```
rename 's/[0-9]+_[rR]elinked_new_//' /path/to/dir/*
```

This will use a regular expression to match the pattern and replace it with nothing on the specified files.

Comment: worked like a charm, I used prename. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @mike87 If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: The script works but I am trying to execute it on a directory with over 30k files and I get this message after about 45 seconds, '
-bash: /usr/bin/prename: Argument list too long
'

Comment: @mike87, that's not the fault of the tool, you'd get the same with `ls *` or so. See e.g. [Solving "mv: Argument list too long"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128559/170373).

Answer (score 5):

Without the `rename` tool, using a simple shell loop with parameter substitution to rename a file at a time:

```bsh
for name in /path/to/dir/*_[rR]elinked_new_*
do
    newname=${name##*/}
    newname=${name%/*}/${newname#*_[rR]elinked_new_}

    # or:
    # newname=$(basename "$name")
    # newname=$(dirname "$name")/${newname#*_[rR]elinked_new_}

    mv -- "$name" "$newname"
done
```

Inside the loop, the value of `newname` is first computed as the filename component of the `name` variable (the last bit after the last slash in the pathname).

The `newname` variable is then modified by pretending it with the directory path and the result of removing whatever text matches the shell pattern `*_[rR]elinked_new_` from the start of the filename.

The code can be simplified somewhat by first changing the current directory into the directory where the files are located:

```bsh
cd /path/to/dir || exit

for name in *_[rR]elinked_new_*
do
    newname=${name#*_[rR]elinked_new_}
    mv -- "$name" "$newname"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really just a comment in response to your problem with "Argument list too long", but it started to look messy in the comment box, so now it's an answer. :)

The reason you're getting that error is that `*` tries to put every file in the directory onto the command line, which has length restrictions.  Instead you can loop over the files (or use `find` to do a similar thing) and call rename on each individually:

```
find /path/to/dir -iname '*relinked_new_*' -exec prename 's/[0-9]+_[rR]elinked_new_//' {} \;
```

Comment: Using the `xargs` variant (`find /path/to/dir -iname '*relinked_new_*' -print0 | xargs -0 prename 's/[0-9]+_[rR]elinked_new_//'`) would be more efficient, I guess.